# Sending json data to a webserver by post always return a 400

Tags: php, json, curl, request, http-post

I know there are some questions like mine in stack, but I really can´t understand whats wrong with my code. If someone could look at it and give some help would be awsome.

I want to validate if the username and password given by the user are ok and if they are proceed to checkout. If not proceed to sign in a new account.
The code i have is this:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$pass=sha1($pass);

$jdados=array("email"    => $email,
              "password" => $pass);

$json_dados = json_encode($jdados);
$len = strlen($json_dados);

$file=fopen("result/test.txt", "w");

$config=array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => "1",
              CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => "1",
              CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
              CURLOPT_POST           => "1",
              CURLOPT_HEADER         => $header,
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $json_dados,
              CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT =>"10"
              );

$curl=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $config);
$result=curl_exec($curl);

$json_result=json_decode($result);

if($result === FALSE){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}else{
    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($file);
}
```

The connection is made, but i always get the HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

Comment: The 400 response is dependent on the server you are making the request to. Without seeing that, there's no way to know why it's returning a 400 error.

Comment: The only information I have about the server is that it accept the request by POST for json data.

Comment: You don't need to pass $url to curl_init and set the CURLOPT_URL, they do the same thing. Since we can't see the URL, we don't know if you're even posting to a URL that works...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The url works.

Comment: Thanks for the help i´ve found what was the error. CURLOPT_HEADER instead of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.